# java.sql.SQLException:Database Locked

Tags: java, sql, database, sqlite, netbeans

I'm having problem "java.sql.SQLException:Database Locked" with this. I did a login screen to my program, after that it's opening a jFrame which I designed. And I made a little button which is working for saving datas in jtextfields into database and showing them to jtable which is right next to the textfield. But after filling jtextfields, when I click to this button, it's giving me "java.sql.SQLException:Database Locked" error. I'm waiting for your help.

PS: If you need login screen's or anything else,just leave a comment or answer, I can edit this question.

```
private void cmd_saveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

      try{          
          String sql="Insert into maintable(\"Ad-Soyad\",Yaş,Konum,\"E-Posta\",\"Katılım Tarihi\") values (?,?,?,?,?)";

          pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

          pst.setString(1, jTextField1.getText());
          pst.setString(2, jTextField2.getText());
          pst.setString(3, jTextField3.getText());
          pst.setString(4, jTextField4.getText());
          pst.setString(5, jTextField5.getText());          

          pst.execute();
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Kaydedildi !"); 

          } catch(Exception e) {          
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
            }             
          }
```

EDIT: Now after clicking button, it's coming up "Kaydedildi" message which is successful in English. But it's showing me an another error.

```
private void Table_EmployeeMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                            
// TODO add your handling code here:

        try{
         int row =Table_Employee.getSelectedRow();
         String Table_click=(Table_Employee.getModel().getValueAt(row, 0).toString());
         String sql ="select * from maintable where İsim ='"+Table_click+"' ";
         pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
         rs=pst.executeQuery();
         if(rs.next()){

         String add1 =rs.getString("İsim");
         jTextField1.setText((rs.getString("İsim")).trim());

         String add2 =rs.getString("Yaş");
         jTextField2.setText((rs.getString("Yaş")).trim());

         String add3 =rs.getString("Konum");
         jTextField3.setText((rs.getString("Konum")).trim());

         String add4 =rs.getString("EPosta");
         jTextField4.setText((rs.getString("EPosta")).trim());

         String add5 =rs.getString("KatılımTarihi");
         jTextField5.setText((rs.getString("KatılımTarihi")).trim());




         }         


        }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);



        }






    }
```

Comment: What database are you using? Is it Sqlite?

Comment: Those are very nasty column names. If you want to save yourself a lot of trouble in the long run, use column (and table) names that don't require quoting.

Comment: yeah sqlite , actually firefox SQLite Manager plugin

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  I tried and i changed it . And i get "Kaydedildi" message which means Succesfull in english. But then a second message coming up with like java.lang.NullPointerException and it's not showing in table.  I edited my question with new codes. Can you take a look ?

Comment: Are you sure you can access the database from your Java code while you have an open connection from another process? Try closing your SQLite Manager and re-run the code. The names are *not* the reason for your "database locked" problem, but quoted identifiers are really a PITA.

Comment: I edited my table with original firefox plugin(not from program) and it's showing up . And i rerun my manager and program. It's still giving me database locked problem.. PS: I got a Login screen. But it's working perfectly with my database and with another table. Just this one giving me problem with inserting data to database.

Answer (score 1):

this is not the way for inserting pst.execute();
use this way

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```