# java.sql.SQLException: database is locked

Tags: java, sql, swing, sqlite

please .i am trying to delete a row from table and at the same time delete a row from sqlite .bute i am getting this error :

```
enter java.sql.SQLException: database is locked
at org.sqlite.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:210)
at org.sqlite.NativeDB._exec(Native Method)
at org.sqlite.Stmt.executeUpdate(Stmt.java:152)
at agenda_p4.Principal.DeleteUser(Principal.java:328)
at agenda_p4.Principal.jButton4ActionPerformed(Principal.java:299)
at agenda_p4.Principal.access$300(Principal.java:33)
at agenda_p4.Principal$4.actionPerformed(Principal.java:184)*




      enter code here  public void DeleteUser(String v){

     String nombreEliminar = v;
     System.err.print("NOMBRE A ELIMINRA ES " +nombreEliminar);

     DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) this.jTable1.getModel();
      int i = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
    String nombre = (String) jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0);


    if (i == -1) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Debes selecioonar una fila");

    } else {

        int ax = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
       "Estás seguro de que quieres    eliminar este registro?");
        if (ax == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {

            try {
                st = con.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {

                //THE ERROR IS THERE IN st.esxecuteupdate:

                st.executeUpdate("delete from Contactos where NombreCompleto = 
                  '" + nombre + "' AND user = '" + nombreEliminar + "'");
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Contacto eliminado");
                 modelo.removeRow(jTable1.getSelectedRow());


            } catch (SQLException ex) {
               System.out.print(ex.getMessage());
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se ha podido eliminar el contacto");
                Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }


        } else if (ax == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Has seleccionado NO.");
        }



    }
```

I have to say i have more querys on others methods  working at the same time .

Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like you're using SQLLite in single user mode and have an active `Connection` open already.  In single user mode, SQLLite will only allow a single `Connection` to be open at a time.  Make sure you either use the same `Connection` or close it when you done...

Comment: Thank you for your answer .how should i close every connection?

Comment: Within a `try-finally` block, when you open a `Connection`, make sure you close it...

Comment: Take a look to [java.sql.SQLException:Database Locked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18466356/java-sql-sqlexceptiondatabase-locked/18495812#18495812).